# Same field with different settings on different content types

Tags: sharepoint

I need your help. My situation is as follows:
My team is developing a sharepoint solution for a customer. We've already developed the branding, webparts and controls necessary to deploy. But we've come to a point that we need to automate column, content type and list creation. In this context, we have the following scenario:

We have a field 'Field A' that is used in content types 'Content Type A', 'Content Type B', 'Content Type C'. All three content types are used in a list 'List A'. But the question is: How can i have three different settings for the same field in the three diferent content types. Like:
In 'Content Type A' the field 'Field A' is required.
In 'Content Type B' the field 'Field A' is optional.
and so on.

Answer (score 1):

You can define that through the SharePoint UI. Once you have applied your content type to the target list, just navigate to list settings then scroll down to the content types list, clicking on one of them will redirect you to the fields used by the content type on this list, from this point on, any changes that you make to your columns you be applied only in this scope.

The key point here is, once you have applied your content type to your list, any modifications made acessing the content type through the list settings (this point is important), will be set only in this context.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but i'm looking for an automated way to solve this problem, since we have to release just a wsp to our customer.

Comment: Have you considered overriding the featureactivated method in order to accomplish this? How are you binding your content types on your lists? I'm pretty sure that you can manage to make your association, retrieve the specific copy of your content type made by your list and then programmatically apply your needs. Let me know if you have any questions or need any help doing this.

Comment: I was looking a xml based way of doing this. But i start to think that the feature activated event is the way to go. Thanks for your help.